# Admin ajax in wordpress is not working

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am using admin ajax but it is not working. Kindly, help me to find out the problem. Here is jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery('#newPostsForm').submit(ajaxSubmit);

    function ajaxSubmit(){

    var newPostsForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
    data: newPostsForm,
    success:function(data){
    jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
    }
    });

    return false;
    }
}):
```

If I alert the var "newPostsForm" , it shown the posted values.but it is now proceeding to ajax. Here is the from I am using

```
<form type="post" action="" id="newPostsForm">    
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addPosts"/>
<!-- input fields -->
</form>
```

An here is the WordPress function I am using. this function is another file. HTML and javascript are in same file

```
function addPosts(){

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);


die();
}



add_action('wp_ajax_addPosts', 'addPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addPosts', 'addPosts'); // not really needed
```

Comment: Is your script running through the PHP process? Try putting the `echo` call into a variable, then alert that to verify the URL is correct + pass the variable to jQuery ajax url option.

Comment: Can you please give me a minute and show me the code how to proceed as per your instruction?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the script is getting processed by PHP before it is sent to the client. Change the code to something similar to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery('#newPostsForm').submit(ajaxSubmit);

    function ajaxSubmit() {
        var newPostsForm = jQuery(this).serialize();
        var url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
        alert("Submitting to URL: " + url);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: url,
            data: newPostsForm,
            success:function(data){
                jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                alert("Got status " + status + " and error: " + err);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you get an actual URL like `https://mysite.example.org` then check that the URL goes to a valid location. If you get `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>` then your code is not getting processed by PHP, and the AJAX call will fail because you are not using a valid URL.

Comment: I am getting like 
Submitting to URL: http://localhost/example/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. I thnk the url is valid.

Comment: Ok, try adding in the error handler function to see if there is some error processing your form. If the `admin-ajax.php` is generating an error, you will get an alert with the error. Otherwise, I am not sure what the problem is, and will need more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that the AJAX URL is not accessible in JS code. If the JS code written into a PHP page then only the code will work. Because the PHP code cant be executed into the JS files.

NOW the solution is to localized the JS file. Please follow the code.

```
wp_localize_script( 'handle', 'settings', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
```

Write the above code just under where you have enqueued your js file. 
NOW in JS file :

```
    jQuery.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       **url: settings.ajaxurl,**
       data: newPostsForm,
       success:function(data){
          jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
       }
    });
```

Hope it will work at your choice.